# Short code that has a lot of repetitions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very skille in programming, but I always try my best. In the follwong code you will see a lot of repetitions. I tried to shorten it, but I think it stays very ugly.

How could I improve this, to make it less repetitive?

```
   $("#searchterm").keyup(function(e){
    var q = $("#searchterm").val();

    if(e.keyCode==13){
        if(q.substr(0,2) == "A;"){
            $("#imagedocu_art").val("A");
            $("#imagedocu_text").val(q.substr(2))
            $("#new_imagedocu").submit();           
        }
        if(q.substr(0,2) == "B;"){
            $("#imagedocu_art").val("B");
            $("#imagedocu_text").val(q.substr(2))
            $("#new_imagedocu").submit();           
        }
        if(q.substr(0,2) == "T;"){
            $("#imagedocu_art").val("T");
            $("#imagedocu_text").val(q.substr(2))
            $("#new_imagedocu").submit();           
        }
        if(q.substr(0,2) == "D;"){
            $("#imagedocu_art").val("D");
            $("#imagedocu_text").val(q.substr(2))
            $("#new_imagedocu").submit();           
        }
        if(q.substr(0,3) == "DD;"){
            $("#imagedocu_art").val("DD");
            $("#imagedocu_text").val(q.substr(3))
            $("#new_imagedocu").submit();           
        }
    }


    if((q.substr(0,2) == "D;") || (q.substr(0,3) == "DD;")){
    if(q.substr(0,2) == "D;"){
      var text = q.substr(2);
    }else{
      var text = q.substr(3);
    }
```

Comment: It's all a matter of style. You may want to consider to add additional details. What is the expected value for `q` it appears to have a specific format. 2 or 3 letters followed by a semi colon, followed by some more characters to be put into the imagedocu_text input. But are the values for q enumerated? What are the requirements for this code?

Comment: Ok the requierement is to check the value of the input and later to modify it! But this is only a snippet! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your first `if` blocks with something like this:

```
var values = ["A", "B", "T", "D", "DD"];
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var len = values[i].length + 1;
    if(q.substr(0, len) == values[i] + ";"){
        $("#imagedocu_art").val(values[i]);
        $("#imagedocu_text").val(q.substr(len));
        $("#new_imagedocu").submit();
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you could use a lookup:

```
var values = { A: 1, B: 1, T: 1, D: 1, DD: 1 };
 var parts = q.split(/;(.*)/, 2);
if(parts[0] in values){
    $("#imagedocu_art").val(parts[0]);
    $("#imagedocu_text").val(parts[1]);
    $("#new_imagedocu").submit();
}
```

In fact your whole method could be replaced with something like this:

```
var q = $("#searchterm").val();
var values = { A: false, B: false, T: false, D: true, DD: true };

var parts = q.split(/;(.*)/, 2);

if(e.keyCode==13){
    if(parts[0] in values){
        $("#imagedocu_art").val(parts[0]);
        $("#imagedocu_text").val(parts[1]);
        $("#new_imagedocu").submit();
    }
}

if(parts[0] in values && values[parts[0]]){
    var text = parts[1];
}
```

Comment: In your second code you have `q.split(";", 2);` but does this work with `DD`? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, it does.

Comment: @JohnSmith Actually I just realized, if you might have `;` after the first one in your string that you care about, you should probably use `q.split(/;(.*)/, 2)` instead. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

A regular expression could replace all of the if checks.

```
if (e.keyCode==13) {
    var match = q.match(/^([ABTD]|DD);(.*)/);
    if (match) {
        $("#imagedocu_art").val(match[1]);
        $("#imagedocu_text").val(match[2]);
        $("#new_imagedocu").submit();           
    }
}
```

Basic explanation of reg exp

```
/       Start of reg exp
^       Start of string
(       Start of capture group
[ABTD]  Match any character included inside the []
|       OR
DD      Match the String "DD"
)       End of capture group
;       Match a semicolon
(.*)    Match all the remaining
/       End of Reg Exp
```

The Match will turn

```
null or ["A;FOO", "A", "FOO"] or ["DD;FOO", "D", "FOO"]
```

Comment: The value of #imagedocu_text I think needs to be the substring of q after the semi colon, might consider `/^([ABTD]|DD);(.*)$/` and then using match[2] for the value of this text.